# Download file from firebase storage using a tag

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download the file onclick from the following URL:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v1/b/brand-250.appspot.com/o/downloadLinks%2FIMG_4584.jpeg?alt=media&token=98634702-5f21-4b9f-bfcb-71566e4526cd

However, when I click the a tag, the page opens up and the file doesn't download. Any idea why the file is automatically downloading?

```js
<a
    className="link__button"
    style={buttonStyle}
    href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v1/b/brand-250.appspot.com/o/downloadLinks%2FIMG_4584.jpeg?alt=media&token=98634702-5f21-4b9f-bfcb-71566e4526cd"
    target="_blank"
    download
  >
    <div className="link__infoContainer">
      <div className="link__left"></div>
      <div className="link__middle">{downloadTitle}</div>
      <div className="link__right"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
```